# Python giving different results when combining two static methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was simplifying code by combining the static method `node_provides_f_through_p_branch` with `deps_search_step` (left) into one simpler `deps_search_step` (on the right).

Note that line 829 on the left returns a node of type `PlanOperator`, which is equivalent to the use of `if isinstance(reuslt, PlanOperator)` -- if A and B as annotated below should be ok.

Yet, I get different results. Something is making the code behave strangely, even though I have no global variables, nor class variables:

[image]

How is this possible?

None of these variables is global or anything related.

This is the code on the left:

```
class PlanExpressionsGraph:
    @staticmethod
    def deps_search_step(G, n, f) -> ResultsPromises:
        """
        Single search step. Returns both the found hits for any of the parent nodes, or continuations
        in case that parent branch still retrieved no result.
        """
        node_deps, continuations = [], []
        for p in G.predecessors(n):
            result = PlanExpressionsGraph.node_provides_f_through_p_branch(G, n, p, f)
            if isinstance(result, PlanOperator):  # if A
                node_deps.append(result)
            else:                                 # else (B)
                continuations.append(result)
        return node_deps, continuations

    @staticmethod
    def node_provides_f_through_p_branch(G, n, p, f):
        f_prime = n.translate_deps_ids(G, p, [f])[0]
        if f_prime in p.get_provided_deps_ids():  # will enter `if A`
            return p  # type = PlanOperator
        else:  
            # will go to (B)
            return lambda: PlanExpressionsGraph.deps_search_step(G, p, f_prime)
```

and this the code on the right:

```
class PlanExpressionsGraph:
    @staticmethod
    def deps_search_step(G, n, f) -> ResultsPromises:
        """
        Single search step. Returns both the found hits for any of the parent nodes, or continuations
        in case that parent branch still retrieved no result.
        """
        node_deps, continuations = [], []
        for p in G.predecessors(n):
            f_prime = n.translate_deps_ids(G, p, [f])[0]
            if f_prime in p.get_provided_deps_ids():  # if A
                node_deps.append(p)
            else:                                     # else (B)
                continuations.append(lambda: PlanExpressionsGraph.deps_search_step(G, p, f_prime))
        return node_deps, continuations
```

*Note: I cannot share input data or the rest of the codebase because it's sensitive.*

By the way, the correct results are with the code on the left.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say for certain since I can't run the code to reproduce the behavior you're seeing, but I expect the difference is that in your modified code some of the variables used by the lambda are changing within the loop, so the lambda is always going to pick up the *last* value of the loop if it's executed later.  In your first example, those values are bound within `node_provides_f_through_p_branch`.

You ought to be able to bind the values in the lambda by using an expression like:

`lambda G=G, p=p, f_prime=f_prime: PlanExpressionsGraph.deps_search_step(G, p, f_prime)`

Comment: Great, I didn't know we could capture the variables like this, didn't even know lambda expressions could have "optional" parameters too :) Great answer, that was it, fixed the issue and now the code is much smaller :D

Thanks!

By the way, if I had used a def continuation(): PlanEpxressionGraph.deps_search_step(G, p, f_prime), should it work too?

Comment: That'd be the same as the lambda -- the trick is that the scope in which you define the function needs to be one in which those values aren't changing!

Comment: @Samwise Yes, that's also my understanding :) Although I find it extremely counterintuitive that the iteration variable itself changes in the scope of the loop, although one would expect that every iteration of the loop has its own scope ...

Answer (score 1):

I think this code might help:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]

callbacks = []

for number in numbers:
    callbacks.append(lambda: print(number))

for callback in callbacks:
    callback()
```

Prints:

```
3
3
3
```

Weird things happen if you capture an iteration variable in a lambda.
Although I have to be honest I don't fully understand it either.

From my understanding, the `number` variable is **not** part of the scope inside of the `for`- loop. Instead, it gets created before the iteration starts and then gets overwritten in every iteration.

Therefore if you want to reference it in a lambda, you have to copy it first.

Comment: Wow, that is crazy, I had no idea that the values were not captured in the lambda. Thank you!